# Fourier series coefficient miscalculation

Tags: fourier-series, bernoulli-numbers

In [a nice introductory paper about Bernoulli numbers](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/78574/18-100c-spring-2006/contents/projects/silva.pdf) that I found, the following claim is made (p. 5, theorem 4.3)

The Fourier series of $x$ is given by $b_n = \dots$ (*not important, it is wrong in the paper as far as I see it, but I corrected the error already*), $a_n$ = 0 when $n \geq 1$ (*seems fine to me*) and $a_0 = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{a_0}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now I don't see how to arrive at $a_0 = \frac{1}{2}$. $T = 1$ since we integrate from $-\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ so then $a_0$ is given by

$$ a_0 = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} x \cos(0 \cdot 2 \pi x) \, dx = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} x \, dx = \left [ \frac{1}{2}x^2 \right ]_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0 \neq 1 $$

The paper is riddled with errors, but I think I'm wrong on this one, since else the complete proof that follows would collapse. Any thoughts?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x$ is odd, since $f(-x) = -x = -f(x)$. In this case, the $a_k$ coefficients are zero.

Comment: You're correct.  After all, how can an odd function have a non-zero constant term in its Fourier series?

Comment: I had a flick through it; the author doesn't seem to know what he's talking about... there are a lot of mistakes. I imagine it's some sort of undergraduate project.

Comment: @TyrCurtis Well I'm not sure. I think the idea behind it is correct, but it is worked-out rather sloppy. I mean really sloppy lol. I was planning to use this proof and have corrected all other mistakes, but I'm not sure of how to overcome this one yet. Any idea?

Comment: I suspect in the paper, the Fourier series is computed for the interval $[0,1]$, not for $\bigl[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigr]$. Would that produce the given coefficients? (It would produce a constant term of $\frac{1}{2}$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Mind reader! My answer was just 2 seconds earlier :). You are right of course, but this is very confusing for me. I rather doubt myself than most papers I find. All the time I was so focused on this $\frac{1}{2}$ that I forgot to notice that the translation also has an effect on the LHS of course. The expression for $b_n$ is also wrong I believe. It should be $(-1)^n$ not $(-1)^{n+1}$, but there is much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last step on page 5, where a translation from $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ to $[0, 1]$ is performed, the $\frac{1}{2}$ on the RHS comes implicitly from the  $-\frac{1}{2}$ that is introduced on the LHS when translating. This has of course **nothing** do to with $a_0$ which the author explicitly states. $a_0 = 0$ obviously and not $\frac{1}{2}$.

It seems that the author copied a proof from somewhere but messed up badly.